# how do you pass a React hook useState() 's callback function to a web component's attribute using Lit HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I am building a custom Web component to use with React, I am using React useState hook and
I need to pass it into my custom Web Component. I know that web component attributes only take strings and if I were to stringify my function it would lose its scope. So here in lies my problem. I am Using Lit HTML and React.

```
    function MyReactcomp() {
       const [state, setState] = useState("");
       return (
            <div className="Wrapper">
               <customweb-component updateState={setState} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: why wouldn't you declare a function that handles the state change and pass it to your update state function?

Comment: ?? setState is a function, I'm not clear what you mean... Web components only take string from there attibutes.

Comment: Using setState does not work due to different scopes being used.  `setState` actually does not exist, or is not visible within the scope of where the jsx is being processed. That's the way it was explained to me.  To some degree that does not make too much sense since the function handler I would think would be within the same scope as the `setState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `onChange={}` on your component, then create a function that will handle the change.

```js
const MyReactComp = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const stateUpdateHandler = (event) => {
    if ( event.target.value.trim().length > 0 ) {
      setState( event.target.value );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="Wrapper">
       <CustomWebComponent onChange={stateUpdateHandler} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

One of the reasons why you cannot directly use `setState` on the `onChange={}` is that the scopes are different, such that `this` when used within the functions may not always be at the expected scope.

Then within your `CustomWebComponet` you would then pass back the value through the following:

```js
const CustomWebComponent = (props) => {

  // You can tie this is an event, or some other
  // normal function where you are processing the return value
  const onTrigger = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onChange(event.target.myvar.value);
  }

  return ( ... )
}
```

If you notice, the attribute name `onChange={}` is arbitrary and you can name it whatever you want to.  Just make sure that you use the same name when you call that function, such as with the `props.onChange()` within the function `onTrigger`.

Comment: Yes sir you are 100% correct, I figured this out last night I just had to listen for a custom event.  Without using redux this might be the only way to do it. Thanks for the quick anwser